# How to get the attribute value from FormControl object in angular2?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-forms

I have limited knowledge in angular2. By using the jquery, we can easily get the attribute value.
e.g
In HTML

```
 <input id="foo" type="text" name="foo">
```

In jquery

```
$(document).ready(
    function ()
    {
           console.log($('#foo').attr('type'));// output foo
    });
```

In angular2, if we use the reactive form, we write input field like this:

```
<input formControlName="name" id="foo" type="text" name="foo">
```

My requirement is getting the value of an attribute(name) dynamically in Component.

Comment: You can still use jquery

Comment: @Bharadwaj No !!! Don't mix jQuery with Angular

Comment: @SurenSrapyan Angular supports JQuery

Comment: Supports but it is better not to use it

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can inject document via `DOCUMENT` token and use it

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document) {
    document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute(...)
}
```

Or use *template reference variables* like

```
<input #foo formControlName="name" id="foo" type="text" name="foo">
```

and in the component use

```
@ViewChild('foo') foo: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.foo.nativeElement);
}
```

The original element will be accessible via `nativeElement` property.

Comment: In recent Angular versions `nativeElement` is no longer a method of a `FormControl`.

Comment: @Neurotransmitter nativeElement is associated with JS, not with Angular

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

Template:

```
<input #myinput formControlName="name" id="foo" type="text" name="foo">
```

Class:

```
@ViewChild('myinput ') input: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.input.nativeElement.getAttribute('type'));
}
```

Comment: thanks, if we have many input fields in a form, using this approach we have to create the same references what we have in form. Is there any alternate idea to handle it?

Comment: In this case i don't see better option than use plain javascript (`document.querySelectorAll(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the reactive way I recommend you this setup:

In your component:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class YourComponent {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup ({
      name: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.myForm.value.name);
  }
}
```

Your html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">Name:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
    </label>
  ...
```

For more information:
[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)